# How do I add a Leviton dimmer switch in this circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, dimmer-switch

I'm trying to add in a dimmer switch where I have two 3 way switches and one 4 way. I've included a schematic of what I have.

How do I make this work? One difference is the 2 wire out of light to the 3 way switch.

This is how my switches are setup. The 2 wire feed to the switch is a little different but I expect this not to matter as it's just a jumper. The pictures are both the same switch 3.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm new to this site.I tried to add a description to each picture but I think it was to long. Please notice that the 2 wire in the box from the light, the black is on the top screw of the switch (different then the schematic) and the white wire is wire-nutted to the black wire, that feeds the 4 way switch. It probably doesn't matter as its just a feeder. I also read that there are better dimmers and I maybe using the wrong one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which one are you trying to replace with the dimmer, BTW. That may make a difference. I'm not certain that 4-way dimmers are all that common.

Comment: I must not have explained well. I have exactly what shows in the diagram, maybe. I thought the light is fed first, but maybe not. I guess I will have to check that to be certain. I have two 3-way switches and one 4-way in the middle. I know that is no dimmable 4-way switch and I expect I would be replacing one of the 3-way. I'm not concerned which switch but really, just so it functions. Is there something that I can check? I didn't pull the light down yet but I can. And thank you FreeMan for the edits. I appreciate it.

Comment: I see what you are saying now and yes, the labels in the picture is not correct but the switches are.  Looking past that please, what you see is what I can visually see. I'm going to pull the light down to check how everything is feed. This was installed 27 years ago. I’m afraid my memory is not as good as I would like.

Comment: Pics showing the wiring attached to the device and leading into the box so we can see which wires go to which cable bundle for each light and all switches (labeling the switches, for example "1, 2, 3 from left to right in the drawing") would be really helpful. There are some pretty dang smart electricians floating around here who will be able to figure out exactly what you've got from those pics.

Comment: If you're replacing one of the three-way switches, just do a direct swap. What's the concern?

Comment: Your question is too open ended considering vast selection of available dimmers. You would get better direct answers with a question structured like "If possible how would I use a Leviton Model #R62-06674-P0W as a dimmer in this circuit?"

Comment: Which one? Does it matter? Last time I tried to make this work, I changed switch 1 and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What switch did you use and did it do nothing or not work properly?

Comment: I used a Leviton Model 1G43K0 dimmer and put it box 1. This was a year ago so I don't recall what happened. I'm sorry. The switch has a red, black and brown wire. I assume the red is the common. I was hoping that someone could read this post as say get a Leviton model 1234 and put it on switch 1 with red to X brown to Y and black to Z. On that note, I don't want to waste anyone's time. I wasn't sure where it should go. I though location made a difference.

Comment: *I thought the light is fed first, but maybe not. I guess I will have to check that to be certain.* -- **You need to be crystal clear on that**. It makes the difference between "can do" and "must pull new /3 cable between lamp and switch 1".

Comment: The two cables on the left are separate from the stuff on the right. Imagine a partition there; you cannot cross that partition.  In particular,  no grabbing neutral from those other wires on the right. (although honestly they look like an unrelated 3-way switch and may not have it anyway).

Comment: I’m working with Leviton to figure out what switch I have. I added in 2 pictures of the switch, if this is at all helpful.  This has turned out to be more complicated then I had expected. The number I gave I thought was the part number. It is only the manufacture date. I will have more follow up when I find out.

Comment: ---I found this on a different site. This is why I asked if location was a factor----

If you want to install a dimmer, I'd buy a Lutron 3-way dimmer.  Identify the 3 switches is at the Line end. The common lug on this Line End switch remains hot (120 VAC) when you toggle its switch. This Line End 3-way is the one you replace with the 3-way dimmer.   Sounds like you tried to install the dimmer at the Load End.  The switch on the dimmer was not sufficient to toggle the load state. That's because the Line voltage coming to it is conditional on the first two switch settings.

Comment: It appears that there's some writing on the back of the switch, but because of the angle, we can't read it. If you can't get a good pic showing that writing (which may be _very_ difficult to do), please transcribe all the text into the body of your question. Someone will be able to ID the model number from that and look up the wiring directions and come up with an answer for you.

Comment: That said, I don't think the comment about which of the two 3-way switches you replace matters, so long as it's wired correctly. I think the quote you gave above from the "different site" is wrong, but I'm not an electrician, so I can't say that with 100% confidence.

Comment: The writing on the back of the switch say Made in China.  I did pull down the light fixture. The light and all switches are just as the drawing shows. The power-source is feed to the light first. It is exactly that same as the drawing.

Comment: The next step is to make sure I don't have a faulty switch.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116463/discussion-on-question-by-plschley-how-do-i-add-a-leviton-dimmer-switch-in-this).